# Finite family of subtori in the torus $(S^{1})^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, geometry, discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems

Working on a problem on matroids, I've already ask a question about some subtori. Here's the link to a previous problem:
[Topological subspace in $(S^{1})^{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844400/topological-subspace-in-s1n)

Anyway, here's another problem related to the previous one:
Let $A\in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{Z})$ be a matrix of $m$ rows and $n$ columns with integer entries.

Let $\mathcal{P}=\{(h_{1},\ldots,h_{m})\in\mathbb{Z}^{m}|\mathrm{rank}(A)=
\mathrm{rank}(A|(h_{1},\ldots,h_{m}))\}$ where $(A|(h_{1},\ldots,h_{m}))$ is the augmented* matrix associated to the inhomogeneous system with vector of coefficients 
$(h_{1},\ldots,h_{m}).$

*http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix

For $(h_{1},\ldots,h_{m})\in\mathcal{P}$ let $S_{(h_{1},\ldots,h_{m})}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be the space of solutions of the inhomogeneous system $(A|(h_{1},\ldots,h_{m})).$

Thanks to [Topological subspace in $(S^{1})^{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844400/topological-subspace-in-s1n), if we denote $\pi:\mathbb{R}^{n}\longrightarrow(S^{1})^{n}$ the projection $(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})\mapsto(e^{2\pi ix_{1}},\ldots,e^{2\pi ix_{n}}),$ we can deduce that $\pi(S_{(h_{1},\ldots,h_{m})})\subseteq(S^{1})^{n}$ is a subtorus of dimension $r=\mathrm{rank}(A).$ The question is the following:

Let $\bigcup_{(h_{1},\ldots,h_{m})\in\mathcal{P}}\pi(S_{(h_{1},\ldots,h_{m})})\subseteq(S^{1})^{n},$ is this set a disjoint union of a finite number of tori?

The answer seems to be affermative: using the Gauss-Jordan algorithm I can see that there are only a finite number of effective translations. However, I haven't found a complete and clean proof yet.

Comment: What does this mean: "the matrix associated to the inhomogeneous system with vector of coefficients 
$(h_{1},\ldots,h_{n})$"? Does it mean to take the matrix $A$ and add another row with entries $h_1,\ldots,h_n$?

Comment: I think there is an error in your notation. Your matrix $A$ seems intended to represent a linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Your space of solutions $S_{(h_1,\ldots,h_n)}$ seems intended to be the inverse image of $(h_1,\ldots,h_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ under this linear transformation, which is an affine subspace of the domain $\mathbb{R}^m$. But instead you write $S_{(h_1,\ldots,h_n)} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, not $\subset \mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a mistake in typing (in my past notation you are right, the problem make no sense). I write down now a correct version. Let me know if is already not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, that union is indeed a disjoint union of finitely many tori. Let me give a proof, after translating the question into the notation of linear transformations.

Your matrix $A$ represents a linear transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ which is defined over the integers, meaning that $T(\mathbb{Z}^n) \subset \mathbb{Z}^n$. Your question is whether the set $\pi(T^{-1}(\mathbb{Z}^m)) \subset (S^1)^n$ is a disjoint union of finitely many tori.

To see that this is true, consider the set $T^{-1}(\mathbb{Z}^m)$, which is the disjunion union of affine subspaces $T^{-1}(h)$ over $h \in \mathbb{Z}^m$. The group $\mathbb{Z}^n$ acts by translation on the subspaces $T^{-1}(h)$ for $h \in \mathbb{Z}^m$, and it suffices to prove that there are only finitely many orbits for this action, because those orbits correspond one-to-one to the components of $\pi(T^{-1}(\mathbb{Z}^m))$. And since $\mathbb{Z}^n$ acts cocompactly on $\mathbb{R}^n$, it suffices to exhibit a positive lower bound to the distance between $T^{-1}(h)$ and $T^{-1}(h')$ for $h \ne h' \in \mathbb{Z}^m$.

To find this lower bound we work in the image $\mathbb{R}^m$, but we do not use the ordinary metric on $\mathbb{R}^m$ given by the Pythagorean formula. Instead, consider the linear subspace $V = T^{-1}(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, let $V^{\perp}$ be its orthogonal complement, and note that $T$ restricts to a vector space isomorphism $T : V^\perp \to \mathbb{R}^m$. Take the $\mathbb{R}^n$ metric restricted to $V^{\perp}$, and push that forward to a metric on $\mathbb{R}^m$ denoted $d(x,x')$ (equivalently, pick an orthonormal basis of $V^\perp$, push that forward to get a basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$, and use the Pythagorean formula with respect to that basis to define the metric on $\mathbb{R}^m$).

So now with two further observations the proof will be done. First, $d(x,x')$ is equal to the perpendicular distance between the affine subspaces $T^{-1}(x)$ and $T^{-1}(x')$ (you can see this by noticing that for any common perpendicular line $L$ to that pair of subspaces, the line $L$ is parallel to $V^\perp$). It therefore suffices to find a positive lower bound to $d(h,h')$ for $h \ne h' \in \mathbb{Z}^m$. And, second, this positive lower bound exists because $\mathbb{Z}^m$ is a discrete cocompact subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^m$ which preserves the distance $d(x,x')$.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for the useful solution. I just a small question related to this one (now I try to find a proof by myself): what if, fixed $(\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{m})\in\mathbb{R}^{m},$ I consider the inhomogeneous system $(A|(\alpha_{1}+h_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{m}+h_{m}))$? At this point $S_{(h_{1},\ldots,h_{m})}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the space of solutions of $(A|(\alpha_{1}+h_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{m}+h_{m})).$

Comment: I think the proof is the same you have done. However, I just have to consider $\pi(T^{-1}((\alpha_{1}+\mathbb{Z})\times\cdots\times(\alpha_{m}+\mathbb{Z}))).$ Is this generalization correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.